# usb keyboard doesn't work in initrd shell

Tags: usb, keyboard, init

I'm working on a custom initrd that I'm netbooting and need to break into a shell.  Unfortunately the USB keyboard doesn't work once it breaks into the shell.

It does however work when I netboot it under VirtualBox.  But I need the shell on the real hardware not VM.

What kernel module is required for USB keyboards to work?

---

By the way, the console output shows the keyboard is detected.  But when I type nothing appears on the screen.  I've tried a couple of different keyboards but without success.  Both were detected but were not usable.